# Finding a random permutation of sequence 1,...,15 for the 15 puzzle in c++

Tags: visual-studio, random

How to find a random permutation of the sequence 1, 2,..., 15 that can be used as the initial state of the 15 puzzle game? The sequence must guarantee the game be solvable. The game will be implemented in C++.

I want to make a 15 puzzle game where repeated numbers are not allowed. An arbitary permutation of numbers, e.g., as returned by `std::random_shuffle`, is not acceptable, as it may render the game unsolvable. So I want unique numbers from 1 to 15 arranged randomly but in a way that they create a solvable puzzle game. Link to the game: https://15puzzle.netlify.app/

Comment: Please specify precisely your problem - don't do it in the comments, but edit your question instead. And ask only one question at a time. What properties do you need from the random numbers? Why they cannot repeat themselves? Please provide an example of the required output.

Comment: As I want to make a 15 puzzle game where repeated numbers can't be allowed. And any combination of numbers in this game is also not solvable. So I want unique numbers from 1 to 15 so that they create a solvable puzzle game. Link of this game: https://15puzzle.netlify.app/

Comment: So you want a generator of all possible "Initial states" in the game of 15? This is easy. I'll think of it later into the (my) evening.

Comment: I've just rewritten your question. Once it has been approved, please tell me if this is what you are really asking about .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

class Fifteen
{
  public:
    static const int N = 15;
    Fifteen(size_t seed) : rng(seed) {}
    std::vector<int> next()
    {
        std::vector<int> v(N);
        std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);
        bool even_permutation = true;
        for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
           auto k = std::uniform_int_distribution(0, i)(rng);
           if (k != i)
           {
               std::swap(v[i], v[k]);
               even_permutation = !even_permutation;
           }
        }
        if (!even_permutation) transpose_pair(v);
        return v;
    }

  private:
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    void transpose_pair(std::vector<int> & v)
    {
        auto n = std::uniform_int_distribution(0, N - 1)(rng);
        auto m = n;
        while (m == n)
        {
            m = std::uniform_int_distribution(0, N - 1)(rng);
        }
        std::swap(v[n], v[m]);
    }
};

// simple test and example of usage
int main()
{
    Fifteen fifteen(time(nullptr));
    auto v = fifteen.next();
    for (auto n: v) std::cout << n << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

**Explanation**

The condition for the game of 15 to be solvable is that the starting sequence is an even permutation of the target one, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#Solvability for a proof. To achieve this, you can start from the target one, 1,...,15, and then apply to it an even number of transpositions (transposition is achieved by `std::swap` if the arguments of `std::swap` are different).

This is achieved in member function  `next()`. A sequence 1,2,..., 15 is formed using `std::iota`.  Then we form a boolean variable `even_permutation` in which we monitor if the number of transpositions (= swaps) perormed so far is even or odd. Then we make a random permutation of the initial sequence using the method often used in the implementation of `std::random_shuffle`, augmenting it with code tracing the parity of the permutation (`even_permutation = !even_permutation`). See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Once we have created a random permutation, we check whether it is even or odd. If it is odd (50% of chances), we must do one more random transposition to make the permutation even. This is done inside `transpose_pair`.

The code is encapsulated inside a class because this approach facilitates handling of a random number generator, which is needed in several different places and we have to make sure the same random number generator is used consistently throughout the code.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, you can accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score -1):

try this you will have random numbers from 0 to 14

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */

rand() % 15
```

Comment: But it doesn't give me the unique numbers.  Example: 1,2,1,5,5 etc. (Same numbers occur more than once)